# Results of/from the analysis

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following sentences is correct, and why? When one is talking about the results of/from an analysis or study, are there instances where both are correct?

Example I:

- Results **from** the regression analysis show that apples are larger in
  the north.
- Results **of** the regression analysis show that apples are
  larger in the north.

Example II:

- They examined results **from** several different analyses/studies.
- They examined [the] results **of** several different analyses/studies.

Comment: Same thing. And google will show this kind of thing.

Comment: With me,**From** emphasizes the source while **Of** emphasizes the result itself.

Answer (score 0):

Both prepositions are valid, though [results **of** is more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=results_NOUN+of%2Cresults_NOUN+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

[Sense B1C](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/result#google_vignette) also uses **of** in the example it gives here:

> result noun (**OF** TEST)
> B1 [ C ]
> the information you get from something such as a scientific experiment or medical test:
> The results **of** the opinion poll showed that most women supported this action (emphasis added).